# How to integrate smart contract data with computation in Ethereum client

Tags: clients

Assuming a contract at address X, and a storage variable Y in the contract. How does Ethereum client fetch such data if it relies on it, for example during proof-of-stake consensus mechanism with on-chain contracts storing validator register, or similar. Code examples would be very appreciated, language does not matter, and links to examples in repositories would also be appreciated. *I asked similar question already, but here I broaden it to general interaction between client and on-chain data.*